# NSPredicate filtration for whitespace and alphanumeric

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to validate `uitextfield` which

- Doesn't contain whitespaces,
- Has at least one letter and one number, and
- Its length needs to be greater than 6.

What is the best way to actually test all of these scenarios in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the NSString method `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` to handle your validation:

```
NSString *str = myTextField.text;

BOOL isValid = ([str length] > 6 &&
                [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound &&
                [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound &&
                [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound);
```